# How can I create a histogram with unequal intervals in R

Tags: r, histogram

I'm having issues with creating a histogram with unequal breaks on R.
I tried to code as what has been answered on this site, however, I'm a very beginner at coding and I'm currently using the options which R offers. I need to create this histogram on this specific program because it's my college assingment.

What I've done so far: I import the data in a .xlsx file, click on "Graphs" and "Histogram"... and then I select "Density" as my y-axis. However I can't select my intervals.

I really don't know what to do. Here's the matrix :
[image: Matrix]

Here are the translated column titles :

- Intervals of BEFi Values
- Number of patients at Session 1
- Number of patients at Session 5
- Number of patients at Session 8

Comment: It sounds like your first step has been to make a chart in Excel. Is this an R question? If so, have you loaded the data into R? That seems like a good first step.

Comment: With that data it seems you should be plotting a barplot. If you want a histogram you don't have to bin the data first. (This is what the first column is telling, the data is already binned.) R histogram functions will that for you.

Comment: You can save your Excel sheet as a csv file and import into R with `df1 <- read.csv("path/to/filename.csv")`. Then, please post sample data. Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df1, 20))`.

Comment: It is possible. Look at ?histogram and the information about the breaks parameter, but as Rui tells you, that aggregated data is unsuitable for a histogram call. Furthermore, most potential answers consider it your responsibility to post data in a form that can be easily handled without implying that we should redo your data entry again.

Comment: @42-  Don't you mean `?hist` ?

Comment: @JonSpring As I said, I loaded the excel file into R, however, when I take the next steps to create a basic histogram, I cannot change the intervals.

Comment: @42- I'm sorry, then, again, I'm a very beginner in coding and R, and I have this college assignment to do. However, I will try my best to understand the answers.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you for you answer, yet, I put this input "df1 <- read.csv("path/to/filename.csv")" with "filename" as the name of my file, and it shows the message "error, cannot open the connection"